# Getting an error when trying to implement editing with callbacks in Vis.js

Tags: javascript, gwt, vis.js

I'm trying to implement [Vis.js "Editing Items Callbacks"](http://visjs.org/examples/timeline/editing/editingItemsCallbacks.html) and I'm using JSNI in my GWT client code, and when im trying to pass:

```
onUpdate: function onUpdate(item, callback) {
    callback(item);
}
```

as an argument to Vis.js´s `setOptions`, it gives me

> Uncaught Error: option `onUpdate` must be a function `onUpdate(item, callback)`

I'm no Javascript developer, but when I look at their examples I can't see what I´ve done differently. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.